# DRAM late and early read and write

Tags: memory, dram

For read operation in DRAM, perform early read mean OE low before CAS is low so doesn't this mean that you just read in junk data ?

For write operation, i don't think there any problem with early write but for late write WE is low after CAS go low so all the data won't be written before write access time end.

I just want to ask if my assumption about these things are correct.

Comment: Regardless of whether you're doing "early" or "late" cycles, you still have to meet all of the timing requirements specified in the datasheet. Therefore, it isn't at all clear what "assumptions" you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for late write WE is low after CAS go low so all the data won't be
>   written before write access time end.

If by that you mean that data will not be written until the end of the access period then you are correct.

Here is the timing diagram for 'late' write on a typical DRAM:-

[image]

If WE is high and/or OE is low when CAS goes low then WE is ignored while OE is low and data is not written until the end of the cycle. This permits reading followed by writing to the same address in a single cycle for 'read-modify-write' operations.

Comment: I enjoyed this. It had been a long time for me, working with DRAM -- 1970s and early 1980s to be precise. And much forgotten, since. Like DRAM, I need refreshing once in a while. Thanks for the time!